# Multi-field form to sql method post request

Tags: php, html, mysqli

My html page contains 5 fields. They are not all necessarily informed.
Method post sends the content of the fields to a php page.
The query must only extract from the database the rows concerned by the field (s) filled in.
The html page sends the request but the database does not return anything. I don't know if the problem is on the html side or on the php page.
I block in front of the complexity of the whole.

main html page:

```html
<tr>
    <td style="font-family: 'Conv_Muli-Italic'; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: #808080;">
        <form action = "ocr6.php" method = "POST">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">TYPE THE WORD OF YOUR CHOICE IN TEXT FIELDS. </th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <table width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"><p>NAME</p>
                    <p>
                        <input name="nom" type="text"  />
                    </p></th>
                <th scope="col"><p>STATE</p>
                    <p>
                        <input name="nom2" type="text" />
                    </p></th>
                <th scope="col"><p>CATEGORY</p>
                    <p>
                        <input name="nom3" type="text" />
                    </p></th>
                <th scope="col"><p>DETAIL</p>
                    <p>
                        <input name="nom4" type="text" />
                    </p></th>
                <th scope="col"><p>ORIGINE</p>
                    <p>
                        <input name="nom5" type="text" />
                    </p></th>
            </tr>
```

ocr6.php:

```php
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "....", "mot de passe", "mabase");
    
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      die('<p>Connexion impossible : '.$mysqli->connect_error.'</p>');
    }
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $nom2 = $_POST['nom2'];         
    $nom3 = $_POST['nom3'];
    $nom4 = $_POST['nom4'];                 
    $nom5 = $_POST['nom5'];
        
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT FROM fiveC2 WHERE name LIKE ? OR state LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR detail LIKE ? OR origine LIKE ? LIMIT 0, 3000");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", '%$nom%', '%$nom2%', '%$nom3%', '%$nom4%', '%$nom5%');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    if (!$result) {
      die('<p>ERREUR Requête invalide : '.$mysqli->error.'</p>');
    }
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $recherche = $row['recherche'] ;
      echo '<p>'.$recherche.'</p>'."\r\n" ;
    }
    
    $result->free() ;
    
    $mysqli->close() ;
    ?>  </p>
        </blockquote>
    </ul>
                      <p><strong> - END OF REQUEST - </strong></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Bharata, welcome to SO. You didnt ask anything! What is your problem?

Comment: Bharata also consider close html tags on both files. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace some of your code with variables, so you can make the code more flexible.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT FROM fiveC2 WHERE $where_string LIMIT 0, 3000");
                                                      ^^^
                                           string containing "name LIKE ?" etc 

$stmt->bind_param($type_string, ...$value_array );
                     ^^^              ^^^
       string containing "sss"         |__ array containing values with 
                                           variable-length argument list (the ...)
```

To create these variables, you have to loop `$_POST` and skip all the empty values.

Create an array with the `input_names => column names` combinations (see NOTE below) and the variables you're gonna use in your statement.

```
$names = [
  'nom'  => 'name',
  'nom1' => 'state',
  'nom2' => 'category',
  'nom3' => 'detail',
  'nom4' => 'origine'
];
$where_array  = [];  //note this is an array!
$type_string  = '';  
$value_array  = [];
```

Then loop `$_POST` to set the variables

```
foreach($names as $input_name => $column_name){
    // if empty: skip
  if( $_POST[ $input_name ] === '' ) continue;

    //add to $where_array: "name LIKE ?"
  $where_array[] =  $column_name.' LIKE ?';  

    //add to $type_string:  "s"
  $type_string.= 's';

    //add to $value_array: "%abcdef%"
  $query_value[] = '%'.$_POST[ $input_name ].'%';
}

  // Test if there was anything at all in $_POST
if($type_string == ''){
   ... oops, there was no input 
}

  // Convert the $where_array to $where_string using " OR " in between
$where_string = implode(' OR ', $where_array);
```

Now you have everything you need. Obviously the `foreach()` goes before creating the query and executing the statement.

For example

```
$_POST : [ nom  => '',              
           nom2 => 'abcdef',        
           nom3 => '12',            
           nom4 => '',
           nom5 => 'Bharata'
         ]

$where_string : 'state LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR origine LIKE ?'
$type_string  : 'sss'
$value_array  : ['%abcdef%', '%12%', '%Bharata%']
```

**NOTE** It would be far easier to give the input elements in your form names corresponding to the column names in your database. You then can directly use the key-names from `$_POST` and its values. It also prevents problems if you in the future add another search element to the form.

```
foreach($_POST as $column_name => $value){
    if( $value === '' ) continue;
    ...
    $query_value[] = "%$value%";
    }
```

Usefull read: [variable-length argument lists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)